# Cannot add spring-jdbc 4.3.7 in project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I try create project with Spring 4.3.7.RELEASE dependencies. Everything works well until the moment when I try adding spring-jdbc dependency. After I do this i have a strange error:

```
Archive for required library: '.../.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar' in project cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file.
```

If I try to use different spring versions what I get whis is error with another dependency.

if work correct only in 4.3.11.RELEASE.
Why it happen?

My pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

       <!-- Spring -->
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency> 

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: you can try `mvn  clean install -U` to reinstall dependencies by force and if you want to see the debug log along with it try adding `-X` after command   and then update project by forcing to update dependencies

Comment: I had a similar issue, but not with spring. I delete the local maven repository for that library, in your case spring-tx and run maven clean verify. Maven will download from Maven repo. This fixed my issue. Give it a try.

Comment: Probably a failed download from Maven. Open up the jar file with an unzip tool and see if it's a valid archive. The solution as mentioned above is to delete it from your local maven repo and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your SPRING dependencies need to be of the same version.
Try maven build..

> maven build --> clean compile install

After that just go to

> Project --> Clean..

Usually this happens when the Maven fails to download the specified Dependency, or is unable to locate it in the local repository.
 
--> clean compile install
should do the trick... had worked for me once.

Answer (score 1):

Еhanks to everyone, and especially paulnuk.
The problem was really in the file with an error. But apparently the reason was in spring-tx.

I try delete it and download again:

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar (261 KB at 1207.7 KB/sec)
```

It solved my problem.